# Can I make this code execution time shorter?

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

This code takes more than 10 seconds to finish. Is there a faster way to do this?

If a particular cell in a row consist of "H" character then hide the entire row and also explain the contents of the cell with a given background color here, it's index code is 19.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TailoredInputs()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i, j, l As Integer

Set ws = Sheets("Inputs")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("A7:A200").EntireRow.Hidden = False

With ws
    .Select
    j = 10

    Do While j <= 149

        If .Cells(j, "J").Value = "H" Then
            For l = 4 To 9
                If .Cells(j, l).Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
                    .Cells(j, l).ClearContents
                 Else: End If
             Next l

            .Cells(j, "J").EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Else: End If

        If .Cells(j, "K").Value = "H" Then
            For l = 4 To 9
                If .Cells(j, l).Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
                    .Cells(j, l).ClearContents
                Else: End If
            Next l

            .Cells(j, "J").EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Else: End If 

        j = j + 1
    Loop   

    Range("Spendinginput").Select  

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub TailoredInputs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i, j, l As Integer, rngHide As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Inputs")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ws.Range("A7:A200").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    For j = 10 To 149
        If ws.Cells(j, "J").Value = "H" Or ws.Cells(j, "K").Value = "H" Then
            For l = 4 To 9
                If ws.Cells(j, l).Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
                     ws.Cells(j, l).ClearContents
                End If
            Next l
            'build the range which will be hidden
            If rngHide Is Nothing Then
                Set rngHide = ws.Cells(j, 1)
            Else
                Set rngHide = Application.Union(rngHide, ws.Cells(j, 1))
            End If

        End If
    Next j

    'anything to hide?  Hide it.
    If Not rngHide Is Nothing Then rngHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    ws.Range("Spendinginput").Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd be looking at would be getting rid of the explicit loop for rows 10 through 149.

You could instead use the [`Range.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to locate the first cell containing `H` in the range you're interested in. As with all potential optimisations, you should check it but I would imagine Excel searching for a value under the covers might be faster than checking every single cell manually.

For example, consider this code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long

Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim t As Long
    Dim x As Range

    If False Then ' or use true for explicit loop '
        t = GetTickCount
        j = 1
        Do While j <= 9999
            If Worksheets(1).Cells(j, 1).Value = "H" Then
                MsgBox ("found it " & j & " " & (GetTickCount - t))
                j = 10000
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    Else
        t = GetTickCount
        Set x = Range("A1:A9999").Find("H")
        MsgBox ("found it " & x.Row & " " & (GetTickCount - t))
    End If
End Sub
```

With `true` in the `if` statement (explicit loop) and a worksheet with nothing but a `H` in cell `A9999`, it takes about 46 milliseconds to find the value. Using the `Range.Find()` method drops that to zero.

Comment: As I said I am a beginner so I chose to go with for loop  instead of Range.Find method. As I don't know how to return the row number so that I can use it to Hide the Entire Row and Clear contents if "H" is found.

Comment: @RohanK, added code to show how it works, and to show you how to get the row out of the range returned from `range.find()` so as to correctly affect the specific row.